# Define two new variables based on the two largest absolute values in two rows

Tags: r

How can I find which of the three variables have the two largest absolute values in each row? Then, I need to make two new variables, one that has the variable that has the largest absolute value in each row and the second that has the second largest absolute value. Thank you.

```
#Sample data
var1<-rnorm(10)
var2<-rnorm(10)
var3<-rnorm(10)
df<-data.frame(var1,var2, var3)
```

Comment: Try `t(apply(df, 1, FUN= function(x) head(sort(x, decreasing=TRUE),2)))`

Comment: That does work really well, but my question was completely wrong.  My fault. What I need are not the largest absolute values, but the names of the variables that have the two largest absolute values in each row.

Comment: @spindoctor same command but use `names(head(sort...)))`

Comment: @spindoctor I posted the variant of my post as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want the column names that correspond to the two largest values in each row, `order` by row with `apply` and get the `names` of the dataset based on the index, subset the first two and transpose the result

```
df[c("varNamesHigh1", "varNamesHigh2")] <- t(apply(df, 1, 
                     FUN= function(x) names(df)[order(-x)][1:2]))
```